# Does java have attributes like C#?

Tags: java

I wonder if they have attributes now and their similarities with this C#'s powerful feature.

Comment: What kind of "attribute" are you talking about? Read the below replies, and please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 8):

Java has "[Annotations](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html)" (since 1.5) which function similarly to [Attributes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

- An article from developer.com: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3556176
- Many handy results: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+annotations